# How to loop through multiple Objects and compare key values to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to loop through multiple objects and compare each date_created key value to a string. These objects are coming from an array that I can map over and output the results as follows: Once I loop through each individual object, if the date_created key value is equal to my string, I would like to push those to an array.

I've provided examples on how I'm currently retrieving the objects, I would just like to know how to loop / iterate over each object and compare the key value to my string.

**Data that is returned initially**

```
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2020-08-10 01:28:59", date_updated: "X", …}

  1: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2019-11-08 02:56:03", date_updated: "X", …}

  2: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2019-10-09 15:05:16", date_updated: "X", …}
)
```

**Code to render list of objects (Map over data that is returned initially to pull objects out of array)**

If this is the wrong way of getting my objects initially, please suggest a more efficient way of doing this.

```
resData.map(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

**Array of Objects Map Result:**

```
{4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
date_created: "2020-08-10 01:28:59", date_updated: "X", …}

{4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
date_created: "2019-11-08 02:56:03", date_updated: "X", …}

{4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
date_created: "2019-10-09 15:05:16", date_updated: "X", …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps. But dont forget `Array.map` is returns array.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const wantedDate = "2020-08-11 01:28:59";
const newArr = [];

const arr = [
  {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2020-08-10 01:28:59", date_updated: "X"},
  {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2020-08-11 01:28:59", date_updated: "X"},
  {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "X", 7: "X", 8: "X", 9: "X", id: "X", form_id: "X", post_id: "X", 
  date_created: "2020-08-10 01:28:59", date_updated: "X"}
]

arr.map((values) => {
  if(values.date_created === wantedDate) {
    newArr.push(values);
  }
})

console.log(newArr);
```